# Progress Indicator for NestList

Tags: dynamic

I have a time consuming function that is going to be iterated in a `Nest` or `NestList` and I would like to know if there is a good way to monitor the progress. I have found a partial work-around, but it requires an extra global variable (n).

```
fun[x_] := Module[{}, n++; Pause[1]];
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n/5]]
n = 0; NestList[fun, Null, 5]
```

Besides being poor coding practice, this is a problem because when I call the Nest from different places in the larger code (for example, make two copies of the above and execute both), all the progress indicators move synchronously, rather than being limited to the `NestList` that is actually executing.

Comment: related: [Button action monitored with progress bar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fun` should not know about `n`:

```
nestListWithMonitor[f_, init_, n_] := Module[{it = 0},
  PrintTemporary[ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[it/n]]];
  NestList[(it++; f[#]) &, init, n]
]
```

`it` is highlighted `Red` but it doesn't matter if its parent `Dynamic` is not meant to survive across sessions.

Now you can use it with whatever `fun` you want.

```
fun[x_] := (Pause[1]; x + 1);

nestListWithMonitor[fun, 1, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [this older post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/227/27951) by Andrew Moylan, I tried combining `Monitor` with your `ProgressIndicator`, then wrapping the whole thing in a `DynamicModule` to limit the scope the `n` variable:

```
Clear[fun]

DynamicModule[{n},
 n = 0;
 fun[x_] := Module[{}, n++; Pause[1]];

 Monitor[
  NestList[fun, Null, 5],
  ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[n/5]]
 ]
]
```

This may become cumbersome for larger code, though. Alternatively, I was wondering if you would consider assigning an explicit context to the global `n` counter, with different contexts used for different copies of the `Nest` code, effectively separating them. Still rather cumbersome though.